# Select Element with Selenium WebDriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser

Problem: Page opens in browser, data loads and renders, but keep getting error which causes "browser.close()" not to execute. I have tried "ID", "XPath" (absolute and relative). Tips on debugging appreciated!

HTML to Extract from:

```
    <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$txtValue" type="text" size="30" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue" class="null" tabindex="1">
```

Code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time

    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Apratt\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver")
    browser.get("https://myreports.restgrowthservices.com/Reports/report/Service%20Center/Accounting/Inventory%20Detail")

    time.sleep(60)

    Concept_ID_Form = browser.find_element_by_name("ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$txtValue")

    browser.close()
```

Error:

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$txtValue"]"}
```

(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Comment: Try to recompile Selenium Binaries again. I mean re-install it.

Comment: Looks like you need to handle the authentication popup before working with the elements.  Also the name and IDs seems to be dynamic. Can you confirm if you can see them in the browser opened through the test scripts?

Comment: I have been working with this for the past day, and it seems to break down in the DOM where there is an HTML element unique to Power BI:  <paginated-report-viewer> which houses an iframe element.  I can access any element prior, but I cannot get the program to recognize the "paginated-report-viewer" element or anything nested inside.